# Is the length of conjugate axis and lactus rectum of hyperbola same?

Tags: conic-sections

At 7:17 of [this video](https://youtu.be/aGVQy-ACDSk) by Eddie Woo, he states that the axis passing through focus of hyperbola is conjugate axis. If this is so, isn't the length of intercept made by this line through hyperbola, just the length of latus rectum?

If so, I can't understand the equations for length of each of these objects. The length for lactus rectum is given as $ 2a(e^2-1)$ and of conjugate axis as $2b$ for the hyperbola:

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1$$
Having eccentricity $e$

Comment: The conjugate axis ($2b$) and latus rectum ($2b^2/a$) are *almost-never* the same length. ... It looks like Woo wanted to draw a vertical line to label "conjugate axis" *somewhere*, and *inadvertently* put it confusingly-close to a focus. At that point in the lesson, Woo's being a bit vague about things in order to drive discussion about what the name even means. He may be anticipating drawing the *conjugate hyperbola* later, and, not wanting to give away that *that* hyperbola's transverse axis is the original hyperbola's conjugate, draws his "conjugate axis" indicator off to the side.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up,  could you give a reference to where I can study the derivation for length of conjguate axis @Blue

Comment: Older texts on conic sections tend to be pretty thorough, but I don't have a particular reference. This may help: The notion of "transverse axis" is obvious enough, like an ellipse's "major axis"; "conjugate axis" is more elusive because you can't *see* it. Except ... If you draw a rectangle of transverse-axis "width", whose diagonals align with the hyperbola's asymptotes, then the "height" of that rectangle matches the length of the conjugate axis; so, in a way, you *can* see it. (BTW: The "conjugate hyperbola" has the same asymptotes, but with vertices on the other sides of that rectangle.)

Comment: Omg it it is just the length between the vertice of conjugate hyperbola @Blue

Comment: See the last sentence of my first comment. :)

Comment: Oh lol, I missed that but I got it's all clear now :P